# Send link of product in FB Messenger Customer Chat | WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, facebook-messenger

I integrated the Facebook Customer Chat on a WooCommerce Store, and everything is working fine, but when a customer starts a new chat on a product page I will like to know which product/page he is looking at to answer accondingly, I'm satisfied with getting the link to it and to be honest it doesn't really matter if it also happens on a Non-Product page.

I've looked around the web but I can't find something useful, I've seen the 'ref' parameter but I don't think it fits my needs.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

[Image with an Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n25xt.jpg)

Comment: The `ref` parameter is meant _exactly_ for such purposes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#customization: _“You may pass an optional ref parameter if you wish to include additional context to be passed back in the webhook event. This can be used for many purposes, such as tracking which page the user started the conversation on, directing the user to specific content or features available within the bot, or tying a Messenger user to a session or account on the website.”_

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the reply, I understand that the 'ref' parameter can be used to track, the problem is how to pass the value in a message, this is because on the other side there's a customer service agent that won't see the value returned in the webhook and the client wants it this way.

Comment: I don’t think there is any way to do that. _“customer service agent that won't see the value returned in the webhook”_ - why not?